# How to use fabric ui textfields with a handler function - is there a way to give them a name?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, spfx

I'm trying to write a handler function for several textfields which a user can type text into. The textfields each have a function which sends the entered data into props and to another class component for submission. I am trying to write an event handler that can handle all the different text fields without having to write a handle function for each textfield. I am using Fabric UI  and I am following guides which all say there needs to be a 'name' property passed from the  which can be used by the handler function so it can update the state. I've tried to add 'name', 'type' and nothing is accepted.

Can someone tell me how to distinguish between the different  by giving each one a unique 'name'?

Here's my current not working/finished handler function to rule them all:

```
public handleObjectWithMultipleFields = (ev) => {
  const target = ev.target;
  const value = target. 

  this.setState({
    [ev]: value
  })
}
```

Here is a function for one of the textfields:

```
private _onJobTitReportToChange = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, newValue?: string) => {
        this.props.onJobTitleReportToChange(newValue);
      }
```

And here is the render in the component with the

```
<TextField value={this.props.jobTitleReportTo} 
           onChange={this._onJobTitReportToChange}/>
```

Thanks as ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not assign name to control directly(if I understand you correctly).

```
<TextField name="txtA"
           onChange={this.handleObjectWithMultipleFields}/>

              <TextField name="txtB"
           onChange={this.handleObjectWithMultipleFields}/>
              <div>

public handleObjectWithMultipleFields  = (ev, newText: string): void => {
    const target = ev.target;
    const value = newText; 
    var _ControlName=target.name;

    this.setState({
      controlName: _ControlName,
      ControlValue:value
    })
  }
```

Comment: Lee - that's helped. My issue was that I was using brackets to assign the name. Such as name={txtA}. Rookie huh?
The code is appreciated and I'll report back if you'll indulge me.

Comment: So I've assigned unique names to all the TextFields in class B. I've updated the handleObjectWithMultipleFields function as above in class A. I'm getting errors with the props using your solution, here's my props for a textfield:
jobTitleReportTo: string;
onJobTitleReportToChange(value: string ): void;
If I change that to onJobTitleReportToChange: string it stops complaining but then in Class B the event function says Type 'string' has no call signatures.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to extract the name and value from the input not just the value.

```
public handleObjectWithMultipleFields = (ev) => {
  const target = ev.target;
  const {value, name} = target;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm getting [name]: value highlighted and it's saying "Block-scoped variable 'name' used before its declaration." Also for value.

Comment: can you show me what are you getting when you console log target
`console.log(ev.target);`